# MFC multithreading: AfxBeginThread vs Boost.Thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, boost-thread

I have an MFC application to which I want to incorporate multi-threading.  Originally I was thinking of using Boost.Thread because of the general ease of development with boost.  However, I'm wondering if there are any gotchas and if I should use AfxBeginThread to be safe in an MFC context?

Comment: Well, sure, you might easily end up needing a CWinThread somewhere and only have a boost::thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this Microsoft article: [Multithreading: Programming Tips](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  It says:

> Accessing MFC Objects from Non-MFC Threads
>
> If you have a multithreaded application that creates a thread in a way
>   other than using a CWinThread object, you cannot access other MFC
>   objects from that thread. In other words, if you want to access any
>   MFC object from a secondary thread, you must create that thread with
>   one of the methods described in Multithreading: Creating
>   User-Interface Threads or Multithreading: Creating Worker Threads.
>   These methods are the only ones that allow the class library to
>   initialize the internal variables necessary to handle multithreaded
>   applications.

I was intending to use the threading in a model view presenter context in order to multi-thread some long running presenter tasks.  As the presenter needs to communicate with the view I think that most likely qualifies as accessing MFC objects (at least indirectly).  Based on that I've decide to go for AfxBeginThread thread creation method for now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to read this article, in the section [Concurrent Programming Improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336130.aspx) this is the best way do things on the Windows platform right now.
Boost slows down your builds and contains a lot of extra stuff you don not need.

Also check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/bb964701) site on parallel programming for more details.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of using `boost::thread` is that its interface resembles `std::thread`'s. There are, however, a few differences. If you ultimately want to use `std::thread`, `boost::thread` will be a straightforward transition.

Answer (score 1):

Just include the following header file and there should be no problems:

```
#include <boost/thread/win32/mfc_thread_init.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have MFC project, please DON'T introduce boost to it.  Use MFC API wherever you can.  Since it has some stuff for threading support, you really don't need one extra library (especially boost) for that.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I write this, it is still unsafe because of this issue in Boost.Thread:

http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Thread-Solution-to-conflict-with-MFC-td3477977.html

(short version that anybody trying this discovers soon enough: merely linking with Boost.Thread causes asserts in MFC initialization)